# Video capture from s-video is all green and pink

Tags: htpc, video-capture, s-video

I bought a Diamond One Touch Video Capture USB device (VC500) to try to use it with BeyondTV in Windows 10. When capturing video from the s-video output from my cable box the video is all in solid green or pink.

I've used the s-video output from this cable box before and never had this trouble but it was going into a different capture card.

Any idea what might cause this? 
[image: Picture of live video]

**--- Update ---**

I tried two other s-video cables and they did the same thing. Then I tried the composite input and it was also all pink and green. Then I remembered that I had told BTV to record Fury last night, just as a test to see what it would do. To my surprise the recording is fine. It seems live TV is jacked up but recordings are ok.

Then I tried starting a recording and then watching the recording. It displayed fine but when I jumped ahead to catch up with the live broadcast it turned all pink and green. I double checked the recording and the file recorded to disk was fine at the beginning and switched to pink and green at the point that I caught up with the broadcast.

It seems BTV handles live broadcasts in a slightly different way than recording to disk.

Any idea what might cause that? I'm suspicious it could be a missing codec.

Comment: Do you have another s-vhs cable to try? Looks like a cable fault.

Comment: This same cable has worked for years but that's a good point. I'm sure I have another cable I can test with.